# URI.join host (authority) injection? (on Ruby 2.3.3)

Tags: ruby

Ruby's `URI.join` seems to overwrite the host part when `//injected_host` is given as second argument:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]

$ ruby -ruri -e 'puts URI.join("http://original.host/", "/path")'               
http://original.host/path

$ ruby -ruri -e 'puts URI.join("http://original.host/", "//injected_host/path")'
http://injected_host/path
```

According to ja_JP version of [URI.join reference](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-join-label-Args), this method behaves following [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) Section 5.2. Does anyone know about this behavior is correctly following RFC or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's implementation is correct.

`URI-reference` starts with `//` is `relative-ref` thats `relative-part` is `"//" authority path-abempty` form.
According to pseudocode in [RFC3986 Section 5.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.2), if a given R is such one, simply overwrite authority, path and query.

```
  if defined(R.scheme) then
     (snip)
  else
     if defined(R.authority) then
        T.authority = R.authority;
        T.path      = remove_dot_segments(R.path);
        T.query     = R.query;
     else
       (snip)
```

Also [RFC3986 Section 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.4) says `http://a/b/c/d;p?q` and `//g` produces `http://g`. This example is also seen in RFC2396 Appendix C.